# Asymptotic expansion for $ F(\beta)=\int_{-a}^{a} dx \, \frac{1}{e^{\beta g(x)}+1}$ as $ \beta \rightarrow +\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals, asymptotics

I'm trying to find the asymptotic expansion for 
$$ F(\beta)=\int_{-a}^{a} dx \, \frac{1}{e^{\beta  g(x)}+1} \;\;\;\;\;\;\mbox{as}\;\;\;\;\;\; \beta \rightarrow +\infty.$$
where $a>0$ and $g(x)$ is a smooth, bounded and even function.

For example $g(x)=cos(x)$

Comment: Do we know anything about the sign of $g(x)$ on $0<x<a$?

Comment: No, we don't know the sign

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression

$$\frac1{e^{\beta g(x)}+1}$$ corresponds to a sigmoid in the vicinity of the simple roots of $g(x)$, making a transition from $1$ to $0$ or conversely. For large $\beta$, the transition is very sharp and tends to a Heaviside step.

Around a root $r$, using the Taylor development to the first order, $g(x-r)\approx g'_r\,(x-r)$,

$$\int_{-a}^a\frac{dx}{e^{\beta g'_r(x-r)}+1}=2a-\frac1{\beta g'_r}\log\frac{e^{\beta g'_r(a-r)}+1}{e^{\beta g'_r(-a-r)}+1}=a-\frac1{\beta g'_r}\log\frac{e^{\beta g'_ra}e^{-\beta g'_rr}+1}{e^{-\beta g'_rr}+e^{\beta g'_ra}}.$$

When $r=0$, the second term is zero, because the sigmoid is symmetric, and the term $a$ just corresponds to the constant value $1$ in the negatives.

In a more general case of several simple roots, you will get the total length of the intervals where $g$ is negative (a constant), plus a small correction term due to the asymmetric location of the root inside $[-a,a]$.

Comment: Thank you; so If I have understood correctly, your  idea is to expand the integrand around the roots of $g(x)$. Is it right?

Comment: @Eric: right, because all information concentrates around the roots, the rest of the function gets completely saturated. (Anyway, multiple roots bring a different behavior.)

Answer (score 1):

As it is bounded we have $|g(x)|\leq M$ or equivalently that

$-M\leq g(x)\leq M$

$e^{-\beta M}+1\leq e^{\beta g(x)}+1\leq e^{\beta M}+1$

$\frac{1}{e^{\beta M}+1}\leq \frac{1}{e^{\beta g(x)}+1}\leq \frac{1}{e^{-\beta M}+1}$

$\int_{-a}^{a} dx \,\frac{1}{e^{\beta M}+1}\leq \int_{-a}^{a} dx \,\frac{1}{e^{\beta g(x)}+1}\leq \int_{-a}^{a} dx \,\frac{1}{e^{-\beta M}+1}$

$\frac{2a}{e^{\beta M}+1}\leq \int_{-a}^{a} dx \,\frac{1}{e^{\beta g(x)}+1}\leq \frac{2a}{e^{-\beta M}+1}$

$\lim_{\beta\to\infty}\frac{2a}{e^{\beta M}+1}\leq \lim_{\beta\to\infty}\int_{-a}^{a} dx \,\frac{1}{e^{\beta g(x)}+1}\leq \lim_{\beta\to\infty}\frac{2a}{e^{-\beta M}+1}$

$0\leq \lim_{\beta\to\infty}\int_{-a}^{a} dx \,\frac{1}{e^{\beta g(x)}+1}\leq 2a$

if $g(x)\leq0$ with $x\in[-a,a]$ then $\lim_{\beta\to\infty}\int_{-a}^{a} dx \,\frac{1}{e^{\beta g(x)}+1}=2a$

if $g(x)\geq0$ with $x\in[-a,a]$ then $\lim_{\beta\to\infty}\int_{-a}^{a} dx \,\frac{1}{e^{\beta g(x)}+1}=0$

(As it is even we have also have $0\leq \lim_{\beta\to\infty}\int_{0}^{a} dx \,\frac{1}{e^{\beta g(x)}+1}\leq a)$

---

Even though $\cos(x)$ changes of sign in the interval, I think you still can get the limit if you write $a=r+n\frac{\pi}{2}$ with $r\in [0,\frac{\pi}{2}] $:

For $g(x)=\cos(x)$ and $a=\frac{\pi}{2},\ (g(x)>0$ with $x\in[-a,a])$

$$\lim_{\beta\to\infty}\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} dx \,\frac{1}{e^{\beta g(x)}+1}=2\lim_{\beta\to\infty}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} dx \,\frac{1}{e^{\beta g(x)}+1}=0$$

For $g(x)=-\cos(x)$ and $a=\frac{\pi}{2},\ (g(x)\leq0$ with $x\in[-a,a])$

$$\lim_{\beta\to\infty}\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} dx \,\frac{1}{e^{\beta g(x)}+1}=2\lim_{\beta\to\infty}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} dx \,\frac{1}{e^{\beta g(x)}+1}=\pi$$

For $g(x)=\cos(x)$, and $a=\pi$

$\lim_{\beta\to\infty}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} dx \,\frac{1}{e^{\beta \cos(x)}+1}$

$=2\lim_{\beta\to\infty}\int_{0}^{\pi} dx \,\frac{1}{e^{\beta \cos(x)}+1}$

$=2\lim_{\beta\to\infty}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} dx \,\frac{1}{e^{\beta g(x)}+1}+\lim_{\beta\to\infty}\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi} dx \,\frac{1}{e^{\beta \cos(x)}+1}$

$=0+2\lim_{\beta\to\infty}\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi} dx \,\frac{1}{e^{\beta \cos(x)}+1}$

$=2\lim_{\beta\to\infty}\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{0} d(x+\pi) \,\frac{1}{e^{\beta \cos(x+\pi)}+1}$

$=2\lim_{\beta\to\infty}\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{0} dx \,\frac{1}{e^{-\beta \cos(x)}+1}$

$=2\lim_{\beta\to\infty}\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{0} dx \,\frac{1}{e^{-\beta \cos(x)}+1}$

$=2\lim_{\beta\to\infty}\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{0} dx \,\frac{1}{e^{-\beta \cos(x)}+1}$

$=2\lim_{\beta\to\infty}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} d x \,\frac{1}{e^{-\beta \cos(x)}+1}$

$=\pi$

So we now know how it behaves for $a=n\frac{\pi}{2}\ $ when $n=1$ and $n=2$, it only grows for n even and with n odd it stays the same and from there one should be able to generalize and finally to add a remainder $r$ between $[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$ that will add $2r$ or $0$

So the limit should be 
$$\lim_{\beta\to\infty}\int_{-(r+\frac{n\pi}{2})}^{r+\frac{n\pi}{2}} dx \,\frac{1}{e^{\beta \cos(x)}+1}=
\begin{cases}
n\pi\ \text{, n even}\\
2r+(n-1)\pi\ \text{, n odd, }r\in[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]\\
\end{cases}
$$

It looks like a sigmoid locally in the intervals where there is not sign change as Yves Daoust said, but on the entire interval taking the limit $\beta\to\infty$ and $g(x)=cos(x)$ is more like an staircase.

Comment: Nadide, any chance you're from Turkey?

Comment: No, why? Does my username sounds turkish?

Comment: Thank you for your help, but the function $g(x)$ could change sign in the interval $\left[ 0,a \right]$ and I'm looking for an expansion of the form: $F(\beta)=c_0+c_1\frac{1}{\beta}+c_2\frac{1}{\beta^2}+O(\frac{1}{\beta^3})$ where $c_0,c_1,c_2$ are constants

Comment: Yes you're right, I edited it, not sure how get the series although, thanks

Comment: Yes, it did sound Turkish.

Comment: "Preciously", I didn't now, can't not unsee now.